# addEventListener seems not to work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

addEventListener is not working, even though i make sure i access the if (the alert works).
I am using firefox so no need for now to "attachEvent" for IE...

```
function addEvent(type,fnName,obj,cap)
{
    if(obj.addEventListener)
    {
        alert("I am here");
        obj.addEventListener(type,fnName,cap);
    }
}

function changeBgColor()
{
    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    nbClicks++;
    if (1 == nbClicks )
    {
        wrap.style.backgroundColor = lightCoral;
    }
    if (2 == nbClicks )
    {
        wrap.style.backgroundColor = lightGreen;
    }
}

function init()
{
    var nbClicks = 0;
    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    addEvent("click",changeBgColor,wrap,false);
} 

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Put a log statement in `changeBgColor` so you'll know if it gets there. Are `lightCoral` and `lightGreen` defined?

Answer (score 2):

There are two immediate issues I see with your code:

1. JavaScript will throw a ReferenceError because variable nbClicks is not **in scope** for the function changeBgColor.
2. You should be assigning strings to the wrap.style.backgroundColor. In this case JavaScript thinks they're more variables, and will throw another couple ReferenceErrors.

Check out this edited version of your code, I encapsulated it all in a closure so all functions have reference to nbClicks:

```
(function(){

  var nbClicks = 0;

  function addEvent(type,fnName,obj,cap) {
    if(obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type,fnName,cap);
    }
  }

  function changeBgColor() {
    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    nbClicks++;
    if (1 == nbClicks ) {
        wrap.style.backgroundColor = 'lightCoral';
    }
    if (2 == nbClicks ) {
        wrap.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
    }
  }

  function init() {
    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    addEvent("click",changeBgColor,wrap,false);
  } 

  window.onload = init;

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not working because `nbClicks` is not initialized in `changeBgColor`.

`var` declares a local variable to the function, in this case, `init`.

if you change `changeBgColor` to

```
var changeBgColor = (function() {
  var nbClicks = 0;
  return function() {
     var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
     nbClicks++;
     if (1 == nbClicks )
     {
       wrap.style.backgroundColor = 'lightCoral';
     }
     if (2 == nbClicks )
     {
       wrap.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
     }
  };
})();
```

Furthermore, `backgroundColor` expects a string, not `undefined` (since those variables were not declared).